# Microsoft Excel weed out all rows of phrases that do not contain at least 1 keyword from a separate list

Tags: vba, excel

In one regular text file I have a list of about 1,000 different keywords (Very straight forward. They are all single words with no spaces and there's a hard return after each keyword).

---

keywordslist.txt

Peter

James

John

Mary

Chris

---

Then I have an Excel file with a list of 100,000 different phrases in Column A (one phrase per row).

I want to delete all the rows that do not contain at least 1 keyword from my first list.

---

phrases.xlsx (These are mostly long phrases, some longer than 254 characters, one phrase per row)

Row 1 "Him and **Mary** are here" (keep this row because there's one or more of my keywords)

Row 2 "The boy called **Peter** and **Chris**" (keep this row because there's one or more of my keywords)

Row 3 "Michael and Ronald are there" (Attention: None of the keywords are present, so delete this entire row)

---

Can this be done in Excel alone? Or do I need a macro?
If it's not so simple as it seems, please guide me in the right direction. I do not have knowledge of VBA or macros but I'll give it my best try if there's no easy way in Excel :)
Thanks,
Alex

Comment: I think you will have to go the way of VBA. Are your keywords going to be on a separate file or are going to put them on a separate worksheet within your workbook? It makes a difference when writing the VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-VBA to do this would be to import your file through the text import wizard into another sheet in the workbook. In your original worksheet, use an array formula (don't forget to Ctrl+Shift+Enter) and double-click the corner to drag down:

`=MAX(IFERROR(FIND(Keywords!$A$1:$A$5,$A1,1),0))`

Keywords is your worksheet with the imported data, A1 is the cell your first phrase is in and let's say you entered this formula in B1. You will have a series of starting position numbers and anything that is zero means none of the keywords were found in the phrases - this is the 0 in the IFERROR formula. You can then filter column B by 0 and delete the visible cells (select > Ctrl+G > Special > Visible Cells Only > Delete Row).

In the example you provided above, the first formula would yield (0, 0, 0, 9, 0). MAX then picks out the highest number.

***EDIT***

As discussed in the comments, this will also pick up partials such as finding "cat" in "catastrophe". To workaround this, you can create a temporary column in both worksheets, adding a space before and after the keywords and phrases:

`=" "&$A1&" "`

Re-do the formula to point to the temporary columns in both worksheets. Adding spaces to your keyword range ensure that it finds only that exact phrase; adding spaces to the phrases will make sure it will find instances where the phrase begins or ends with the keyword.

Comment: nethy, thanks again :) Quick question.. I'm getting some starting position numbers other than 0 although the complete keyword is not there but the characters do match, so I suspect.. Is it possible that the array formula may be looking for the existence of all the characters instead of complete words? Can this be modified?

Comment: It should only pick up the full word, however if it is part of a larger word, it will pick that up too. For example, it will find "cat" in "catastrophe". Can you give an example of the phrase and position?

Comment: yup, that's exactly what it's doing.
Here's my keywords list:
H175
H23
H2342
H39
H40
H49
H5
H5127
H5660
H59
H62
H77
H887

Comment: ----
and here's my phrases list:
----
aaron H175 7 /nextrow/
aaron’s H175 9 /nextrow/
aaronites H175 11 /nextrow/
abagtha H5 9 /nextrow/
abana H71 0 /nextrow/
abarim H5682 8 /nextrow/
abated H2637 0 /nextrow/
abated H5127 8 /nextrow/
abated H7043 0 /nextrow/
abated H7503 0 /nextrow/
abda H5653 6 /nextrow/
abdeel H5655 8 /nextrow/
abdi H5660 6 /nextrow/
abdiel H5661 8 /nextrow/
----
These are dictionary entries for each word that is numbered. So the phrases are much longer, but I figure you can get the idea. :) Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: Let's create a Blank Workbook and a new Module in VBE then paste in the code, save as macro-enabled workbook (.xlsm), change macro security setting, reopen this .xlsm file.

Press Alt-F11 in Excel to open Visual Basic

Click Insert -> Module

[image: Insertmodule]

Double Click Module1 or whatever it just created

[image: Module1]

Paste in the code below

```
Const ForReading = 1
' Change these two below to match your file path
Const KeyWordsFile = "C:\Test\keywordslist.txt"
Const PhrasesFile = "C:\Test\phrases.xlsx"    

Sub SO_19150262()
    Dim aKeywords As Variant, oWB As Workbook, oWS As Worksheet
    Dim R As Long, i As Long, bDelete As Boolean, sTmp As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Read the Keywords file into aKeywords (array)
    aKeywords = GetKeywords(KeyWordsFile)
    Set oWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=PhrasesFile, ReadOnly:=False)
    Set oWS = oWB.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Change this to match yours
    ' Start comparing from bottom of used data
    For R = oWS.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row To 1 Step -1
        bDelete = True
        sTmp = "Deleting Row " & R
        For i = 0 To UBound(aKeywords)
            If Len(aKeywords(i)) > 0 Then
                Application.StatusBar = "Checking Row " & R & " for keyword """ & aKeywords(i) & """..."
                If InStr(1, oWS.Cells(R, 1).Value, aKeywords(i), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    sTmp = "Keeping Row " & R & ", Keyword(" & i & "):""" & aKeywords(i) & """"
                    bDelete = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Debug.Print sTmp
        If bDelete Then oWS.Rows(R).Delete
    Next
    oWB.Save
    Set oWS = Nothing
    Set oWB = Nothing
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Function GetKeywords(sKeyFile As String) As Variant
    Dim aKeys As Variant, oFSO As Variant, oFile As Variant

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(KeyWordsFile, ForReading)
    If (oFile.AtEndOfStream) Then
        aKeys = Array()
    Else
        aKeys = Split(oFile.ReadAll, vbCrLf) ' Might need to change to vbCr or vbLf if unix text file
    End If
    Set oFile = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
    GetKeywords = aKeys
End Function
```

Then in Excel, Save-As -> "Excel macro-Enabled Workbook"

[image: SaveAs]

In Developer tab, click the Macro Security (I guess you will not be signing your macro so change to enable all macro for this)

[image: MacroSecurity]

Select Enable all macros... then click OK

[image: EnableAllMacro]

Close and reopen this .xlsm and click Macros in Developer tab, select SO_19150262 and click Run:

[image: RunMacro]

Comment: Hi PatricK, thanks for helping! Please forgive my ignorance.. 

1. I opened the phrases.xlsx file

2. I went to "Developer" tab, then clicked on macros. In the Macro name: I put "TestingMacroFromPatricK" and I clicked "Create".

3. It opened up VBA and I got this in front of me now:
Sub TestingMacroFromPatricK()

End Sub


4. At this point I don't know where I need to paste the entire code you provided me with.
I tried pasting it in between, like shown here below:
Sub TestingMacroFromPatricK()
(I pasted it here)
End Sub

Comment: 5. Now when trying to save, it says: "The following features cannot be saved in macro-free workbooks. VB project."
And my options are to continue saving as a macro-free workbook or choose a macro-enabled file type. So I saved it as "phrases.xlsm". Is this correct?

Comment: 6. At this point I still haven't changed this:
' Change these two below to match your file path
Const KeyWordsFile = "C:\Test\keywordslist.txt"
Const PhrasesFile = "C:\Test\phrases.xlsx"
So I'm changing it now to:
Const PhrasesFile = "' Change these two below to match your file path
Const KeyWordsFile = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\keywordslist.txt"
Const PhrasesFile = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\phrases.xlsx"\phrases.xlsx"
And now I saved it again, just in case.

Comment: 7. Back in Excel, I go to "Developer" tab, click "Macros" and I have 2 choices to run: "SO_19150262" or "TestingMacroFromPatricK".
I'm trying to run "TestingMacroFromPatricK" and I get a "Compile error: Expected End Sub". So I put that in and save.

8. Now I try to run it again and no errors, but nothing else happens! So I think.. maybe now my "Const PhrasesFile =" should point to the new "phrases.xlsm" ? I tried changing the path but nothing happens either.

Comment: 9. So I try to run "SO_19150262" instead, but I get a different Compile error: "ByRef argument type mismatch".

This is where I'm stuck and don't know how to proceed :(